# windows phone 8 error -

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, emulation

My brand new laptop OS is windows 8.1 64 bit , X-64 based proccer, yet when I try to use the windows phone 8 emulator  I recive an error "windows phone emulator requires hyper-v. your PC is missing the following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V: Windows 8 Professional (64-bit)"

I looked up in "Turn some windows features on/off" and I couldn't find the option but I know my PC support Hyper-V.
Do I have to replace my OS, or is there a way to solve it? If thereisn't a way, maybe you know another emulator software you can suggest?

Comment: Do you have "Windows 8 Professional (64-bit)"?  If you have Home edition it's not going to work.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's a setting in the BIOS.

Comment: Actually it's the VTx feature which is in the BIOS. But you need it in order to have Hyper-V. I don't know if it could cause it not to appear in the list.

Comment: I thing I have the Home edition cuz it doesn't say "Professional ".
Anyway, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul said, you have to have Windows 8 Professional in order to turn on hyper-v.